# Django forms with multiple access

Tags: python, django, angular, django-models, django-rest-framework

After creating a multi-stage form.
How do I restrict the access to the particular part of the form to a particular user.
Suppose I have 3part of the form... User1 can access part1 of the form after that user2 can access the part2 of the form and so on...

Admin can View and access all part of the multi stage form

Comment: I guess you want to have 3 forms.

Comment: If you're using drf token auth you can check the user's token and if the token belongs to a user not authorized to access that section of the form, they will not be able to continue.